# Warning: 'Conflicting types...' when creating Objective-C (ios) initializer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, constructor, initialization

I want to be able to initialize one of my classes with something that looks like this

```
ModelClass *aModelClass = [[ModelClass alloc] initWithXML:imageXML];
```

So this is what I wrote in the **interface** file:

```
-(id)initWithXML:(TBXMLElement *)imageXML
```

and like this in the **implementation** file:

```
-(id)initWithXML:(TBXMLElement *)imageXML
{
    self = [super init];

    if(imageXML) 
    {
        // do stuff with self.foo
        return self;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

So I have declared it in the interface file and also the implementation file. But the error I get on both is that they are conflicting. So how do I do this if not declare the exact same method signature in both?

The error I now get is:

> Conflicting types for
>   '-(id)initWithXML:(TBXMLElement
>   *)imageXML'

I was looking mostly at [this article](http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-initializers.html) to understand how to do this and understanding how it should be done in Objective-C but this has not clues as to help me with my problem.

Comment: You're missing a semicolon after the declaration; I assume that's just an error in your transcription here, though.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning `nil`.  You <strike>must</strike> should always return an object.*(Thanks to Josh for pointing out that you don't always need to return an object)*   Like this:

```
-(id)initWithXML:(TBXMLElement *)imageXML {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        if(imageXML) {
            // do stuff with self.foo
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

---

Also, I just remembered encountering something similar to that myself.  Make sure you import `TBXML.h` in both classes, the `ModelClass`, as well as the controller where you are creating the `ModelClass`.  The problem is that the compiler doesn't know what a `TBXMLElement` is, so you need to instruct it by importing the relevant header(s).

Comment: Thanks for the catch, but that doesn't solve the multiple types warning I am getting.

Comment: No difference, it took away (id) in the beginning and that solved it for some reason.

Comment: Wait what? What did you substitute it with, then?

Comment: while returning nil, you should release the object.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you _can_ return `nil` -- if the call to [super init] fails.

Comment: I copy pasted the method signatures before i posted this and it didn't work. I tried many times and then tried even to remove arbitrary parts of the method bodies in order to find the reason for the problem. Nothing worked, then suddenly I copy paster the method signatures again and it did work. Maybe it was that I changed what is returned or there was something peripheral that got solved as I  repeated writing those parts of the code. THanks for help

Comment: Actually, in this case he is deliberately returning nil. The init method is absolutely fine. You always follow the pattern: Call [super init] to make sure everything will be fine when dealloc gets called. If the result of [super init] is not nil, then you check your parameters and if you decide you don't want to return an object, you return nil. He decided that you can't have an object with the image. Perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be it, but you do appear to missing a semi-colon in your interface definition:

```
-(id)initWithXML:(TBXMLElement *)imageXML
```

should be

```
-(id)initWithXML:(TBXMLElement *)imageXML;
```

but maybe that is just a copy and paste error when you were writing up your question.

Also make sure you

```
#import "TBXML.h"
```

in ModelClass.h (if you include it in ModelClass.h then other .m files that import ModelClass.h will also get the definitions for `TBXMLElement` which they will need.

Comment: This might have actually been the problem. I didn't do this initally, sadly even though I tried to get to the root cause I suddenly couldn't replicate the problem and I wasn't sure what solved it.

Comment: Well, either way glad your problem is solved. Perhaps add an answer of your own, if you do not want to accept either of the two you have, and accept it. This just so that people know that you are not still looking for an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the help! 
I fondled in the dark for while and didn't find the cause of the problem although both solutions posted here by "sudo rm -rf" and "idz" seem likely.

I worked after I simple deleted my code and wrote it again from the beginning.